# Macro to fill blank cells within a range

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say i have the range of cells A1:C3 and i need to fill in any empty cells from the range with the value that is in cells A4:C4, the emplty cells in column A will be filled with the value of A4, those in column B with the value from B4 and so on.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please share your code!

Comment: Also, if this is for a homework, please say it in your question. Make sure you provide an example what you already tried and some data sample to make sure everyone understands the same question.

Comment: Hi! Stackoverflow is here to answer specific programming questions. This question reads like "Build me a program to that will fulfill these requirements. Go.". If you are stuck with a specific part of this, or you have some code that isn't doing what you like, that would be a more appropriate question for this site. For more info you can check [what's on topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dynamic by both `Rows` and `Columns`. The assumption is that the last row is the cell that will be used to fill in blanks. If the assumption is true, you can add rows and columns as you please and this code will work without any modification

1. Determine last row in range (Determined by `Column A`)
2. Determine last column (Determined by last row in step 1)
3. Loop through rows column by column
4. Fill blanks with the value associated with the last row if blank

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<== Update Sheet Name
Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long, r As Long, c As Long

LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = ws.Cells(LRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For c = 1 To LCol
        For r = 1 To LRow - 1
            If ws.Cells(r, c) = "" Then
                ws.Cells(r, c).Value = ws.Cells(LRow, c).Value
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Both examples below are from the same macro. Notice that it works as expected for your propsed example (`4 Rows x 3 Columns`) and for other table sizes like the example on right (`8 Rows x 7 Columns`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all the cells in **A1:C3** are empty, then consider:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Range("A1:C3").Value = Range("A4:C4").Value
End Sub
```

If some of the cells in **A1:C3** are not empty, then use:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks2()
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            If Cells(i, j) = "" Then
                Cells(4, j).Copy Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.. just change `Worksheets(1)` to your desired Worksheet and `4` to desired row

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rng = .Range("A1:C3")
    For each cel in rng
        If Len(Trim(CStr(cel.Value))) = 0 Then cel.Value = .Cells(4, cel.Column).Value
    Next
End With
```